# Need help to get auto suggest to display (in list-form) the fetched/matched data from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, autosuggest

I am having problem solving the following: 
I have a form with one search field (with autosuggest). 
In this field I would like to be able to type a **name or mobile.nr**. 
Based on what I type I get suggestions, so typing letters or numbers returns: name and mobile based on matches in the database. 
If no match is found a "create customer" button shall appear. 
If a match is found a "create work-card" button shall appear.

In my code below I am getting all the data from my customer table, but I can not figure out how to make it show in list form with one row per result including the persons name and mobile in the autosuggest ex: 
suggestion 1:   name and mobile
suggestion 2:   name and mobile
suggestion 3:   name and mobile
etc…..

My autosuggest script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        //autocomplete
            $(".input_name_or_mobil").autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 1        
            });             
    });
</script>
```

The script searches in my **search.php** file:

```
<?php
if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )
exit;

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db('workcard');

$results = mysql_query('SELECT name AS shout FROM customer WHERE name LIKE "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" UNION SELECT mobil FROM customer WHERE mobil LIKE "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 10', $connect);

$data = array();
if ( $results && mysql_num_rows($results) )
{
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
{
    $data[] = array(
        'label' => $row['shout'],
        'value' => $row['shout']
    );
}
}

echo json_encode($data);
flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you question:

You are using `UNION`, so the records will be after each others.

Try this:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT name, mobile FROM customer WHERE name LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) . "%' OR mobil LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) . "%' ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 10", $connect);
$data = array();
if ($results && mysql_num_rows($results)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['name'] . " " . $row['mobile'],
            'value' => $row['name'] . " " . $row['mobile']
        );
    }
}
```

In this code, you will be get back the name and mobile fields form the table, and all the records wher name **OR** mobil is similar than the term.

Use mysqli_ function because mysql_ functions are deprecated.

Comment: I do not understand why you create an array `$data = array();` before the if statement. Am I wrong when saying that you create an array again and fill it in `$data[] = array(...`
  
Why do I need the `$data = array();` before the if statement?

Comment: This is my habbit. I am using this, because lately in these situation i am looping through on the array. If i do not initialize the array, before the foreach i need to check, is the array exists. This is becuase if there was no result, there are no `$data` variable.